# Proving a subset of a vector space that is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication has an additive identity and inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given a theorem that follows:

If $W$ is a non-empty subset of a vector space $V$ s.t. for any $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\in W$ and for any $a,b\in \mathbb{F}$ the vector $a\textbf{x} + b\textbf{y}$ is also in $W$, then $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Because $W$ is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, most of the requirements to be a vector space are fulfilled. But I am trying to show that the additive identity and inverse are true.

Yes, $\textbf{0}\in V$ and $W \subset V$, but that does not imply $\textbf{0}\in W$. Similarly with $-\textbf{x}\in V$.

Any thought to get me started on proving these points?

Comment: But aren't you assuming that $W$ is closed under scaling, so $-x=(-1)x$ is definitely in $W$ when $x \in W$.  And as $W$ is non-empty, it's got some $x \in W$, but then $0x=$....

Comment: Also, as soon as you know that $W$ is closed under negatives, you already get $0 \in W$:  given any $x \in W$, we have $-x \in W$, and your assumption is then that $x-x=0\in W$.

Comment: @Randall I did not know we could just assume that $a=-1\in \mathbb{F}$. I guess I need to review fields.

Comment: Yes, that is part of the structure of a field.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\b}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} \mathbf{0}$ is indeed in $W$, because of the closure under linear combinations:

$$W \ni a \b{x} + (-a) \b{x} = \b 0 $$

This holds since $a \in \mathbb{F} \implies -a \in \mathbb{F}$ (since $\mathbb{F}$ is a group under addition) and $-\b{x} = (-1) \b{x}$.

Likewise, one has the additive inverses:

$$W \ni 0 \b{x} + (-1) \b{x} = - \b{x}$$

Comment: So since $W$ is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, $a\in \mathbb{F} \Rightarrow (-a)\in \mathbb{F}$, which means $a\textbf{x}$ and $-a\textbf{x}$ are valid by scalar multiplication. And by vector addition, $a \textbf{x} + -a \textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$ which implies $\textbf{0}\in W$?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.